# Pathfinder 2e - Monk Mountain Stance and Trip

Tags: monk, pathfinder-2e, trip

The Monk's Mountain Stance has the following requirement:

> You are unarmored and **touching the ground.**

The trait Stance says as follow:

> A stance is a general combat strategy that you enter by using an action with the stance trait, and that you remain in for some time. A stance lasts until you get knocked out, **until its requirements (if any) are violated**, until the encounter ends, or until you enter a new stance, whichever comes first. After you use an action with the stance trait, you can’t use another one for 1 round. You can enter or be in a stance only in encounter mode.

Because of this, the question I have is: Does the Trip action tripping the  Monk breaks the "touching the ground" requirement of Mountain Stance?

Comment: Do you mean performing the trip, or being tripped?

Comment: Being tripped, I'll clarify the OP

Answer (score 7):

### This is a GM call

Each GM will have to rule what constitutes touching the ground...

### But probably not

Trip leaves you prone on the ground. Touching the ground should generally be any time you're not flying... and probably not jumping, swimming, climbing, etc.

While it's *technically* true that you probably leave the ground momentarily when you're tripped, you also *technically* leave the ground when you move quickly such as running. In these cases it is probably not a good call to have that count as 'not touching the ground' for the minute amount of time that it accounts for. There are plenty of other effects that may or may not accomplish this, but I see no reason to add that power to Trip.